# Strict 2-Phase Locking Example where Commit order \neq serial order

Tags: transactions

Is there an example where the commit order doesn't equal the serial order for some transactions? I'm struggling to come up with one any any help/hints are appreciated!.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider two transactions T1 and T2 and a schedule:

```
T1: a=r1[x] w1[y,a]            c1

T2:                 w2[x,b] c2
```

This corresponds to a serial order T1, T2, but the commit order is T2, T1.

This schedule is allowed by S2PL (it releases read locks before commit), but not allowed by SS2PL, which guaranties [Commitment ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_ordering)